# How to add request header to vlcMobilePlayer?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, vlc

I am using *MobileVLCKit* to play streaming video and I can play videos with URL.
But, how to play videos with some special header?
Just like sending *HTTP requests*.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

From https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

```
HTTPS input (access)
      --http-continuous, --no-http-continuous 
                                 Continuous stream
                                 (default disabled)
          Keep reading a resource that keeps being updated.
      --http-forward-cookies, --no-http-forward-cookies 
                                 Cookies forwarding
                                 (default enabled)
          Forward cookies across HTTP redirections.
      --http-referrer=<string>   Referrer
          Provide the referral URL, i.e. HTTP "Referer" (sic).
      --http-user-agent=<string> User agent
          Override the name and version of the application as provided to the
          HTTP server, i.e. the HTTP "User-Agent". Name and version must be
          separated by a forward slash, e.g. "FooBar/1.2.3".
```

You can provide these CLI args to libvlc through MobileVLCKit when calling the MobileVLCKit equivalent of `libvlc_new`.

Comment: Sorry, not really understand what u mean. I use https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit  this library. And using swift to code. What I want is before I set URL to VLC media. I want to set header for it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to add "http-referrer" when init vlcmediaplayer,or before play video,however it's not working